# minus vs delete where exist in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `CREATE TABLE` query which can be done using two methods (create as select statement for thousands/million records):

First method:

```
create table as select some data minus (select data from other table)
```

OR

first i should create the table as

```
create table as select .....
```

and then

```
delete from ..where exist.
```

I guess the second method is better.For which query the cost is less?Why is minus query not as fast as the second method?
EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the create statement has join from two tables as well.

Comment: The first one is better. It will generate less REDO and UNDO.

Comment: The first method is better as you are only creating the records you need.

Comment: but i have checked and the second method is taking less time overall.

Answer (score 6):

The minus is slow probably because it needs to sort the tables on disk in order to compare them.

Try to rewrite the first query with `NOT EXISTS` instead of `MINUS`, it should be faster and will generate less REDO and UNDO (as `a_horse_with_no_name` mentioned). Of course, make sure that all the fields involved in the `WHERE` clauses are indexed!

Comment: The `minus` will also suppress any duplicates that were in the source table, which may not be an issue but might be another reason to use `not exists` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The second one will write lots of records to disk and then remove them. This will in 9 of 10 cases take way longer then filtering what you write in to begin with.

So if the first one actually isn't faster we need more information about the tables and statements involved.